# Get message payload attribute using Mule expression

Tags: jdbc, expression, mule, endpoint

I have set a `default-service-exception-strategy` which route and application error to various outbound endpoints.

One of this endpoints is a jdbc connector endpoint which updates the database with the error message.

I'd like to get an attribute from the payload which filters the rows to be updated.
Which expression should I use to get the attributes values to my query?

```
UPDATE  dtb_controle_processo.cnpr.tbl_controle
SET     cod_situa_seque = 'FAILURE'
WHERE   cod_situa_seque = 'INICIADO'
AND     cod_modul       = #[message.payload.module]  --- WHAT EXPRESSION ?
AND     cod_proje       = #[message.payload.project] --- WHAT EXPRESSION ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`#[bean:module]` and `#[bean:project]` should do the trick. See the [reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Expressions+Configuration+Reference#ExpressionsConfigurationReference-ExpressionEvaluatorReference).

Comment: You can also use #[ognl:module]" and #[ognl:project]".